# Opposites of RSVP

Tags: single-word-requests

I've googled the subject and got hits only along the lines of [DRSVP and NRPSVP](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090822043507AAblmQa), which seem like an awkward mix-up of inter-linguistic confusion (the former) and incomprehensible abbreviation demanding understanding of foreign grammatic.

Furthermore, I realized that, since RSVP means that **each** invitee should reply (independently of the attendance ability), there's no unambiguous opposite. There could be, e.g. *reply-only-if-you're-coming* or *reply-only-if-you're-not-coming*.

Moreover, that acronym is used mostly for confirmation of attendance at social gatherings and, sadly, is not that widely known to begin with (at least amongst people in the companies I've worked for).

At one place, we used *MRIA* (or, at another place, *ORIA*) at the end of an e-mail or SMS to declare that no reply (including, but not limited to, "*OK*") was needed **under the condition** that no changes were to be proposed. A, sort of, opt-out, so to speak.

However, I've found that *MRIA* is as seldom recognized as *RSVP's* negations mentioned above. And I'm tired explaining that *MRIA* stands for "*Missing Response Implies Agreement*" (or "*Omission of Reply Indicates Acceptance*").

Is there a term/acronym to be used at the end of e-messages to suggest that omission of reply is equivalent with accepting the contents?

Comment: What's wrong with just spelling it out (since so few understand your made-up acronym)?

Comment: @Mitch Time/space consumption.

Comment: Well, it looks like you will just have to expend the time and space to explain MRIA or ORIA once for all, or each time, or to spell it out each time. I could suggest QTC for *qui tacet consentit* (which would particularly confuse cardiac-care adepts) or QTCV for *qui tacet consentire videtur,* or maybe SNOFHYP for *speak now or forever hold your peace,* but the problem would surely replicate itself with any of these.

Comment: _ORIA_ seems particularly ill-fitting here. Before you told us what it meant, I had—from the context—deduced that it must mean _Only Reply If Absent_, which is the exact opposite of what you wanted it to mean. I agree that this is not the place for saving time or space to such a degree. Just write “Reply only if you do not agree” or something like that.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like the immoral Vogon argument: 'You didn't know your planet was scheduled for demolition? The legally required notices have been on public display on Pluto for the mandatory 10 years' (owtte). 'Nobody has objected.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think I failed to convey the context of the usage of *ORIA*. I've experienced on many occasions that people feel expected to reply "*OK*" or "*I see*" etc. and I'd like to have a marker to let them know that the keeping the social convention in the conversation is unnecessary. I prefer a more blunt and information dense exchange of messages. :)

Comment: "Regrets only" is used on invitations and is reasonably short.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not be using initialisms that no one will recognize and few will figure out.  Instead you should explicitly state what you do or do not require or expect of your correspondents as a matter of courtesy.

Comment: Agreed on the point made. I was hoping that there existed such an acronym and that it was our ignorance that kept us from using it. I'm guessing I'll have to define it for the organization and introduce it myself.

Comment: ... IYOSYCDWYL(WR)BDEMTJ.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My introduction would start by **spelling out** to the other what I indent to introduce, hehe. Just out of curiosity - what's that acronym?

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten: That seems to double the work rather than halve it. What does my nonce-initialism (I use 'acronym' for those that are pronounced as words) stand for? I've forgotten, but believe me, it was good!

Answer (score 1):

Just because no one recognized WYSIWYG or WTF, that doesn't mean new acronyms are illegal and shouldn't be created!
May I suggest the acronyms DNR (do-not-reply/respond) and a more polite NRN (no-response-necessary); or RIN (respond/reply-if-necessary)?

Comment: But DIY-isms are definitively off-topic on ELU. WDYRACTSR?

Comment: [DNR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_not_resuscitate) is already taken.

Comment: My apologies. But since no 'definitive' answers can be found, I thought perhaps if we pretended English was a living language new words and acronyms wouldn't be illegal or off-topic. As for DNR being taken, I'm not surprised. However, words evolve into new meanings, so perhaps the popular meaning for acronyms will also evolve.

Comment: English _is_ a living language, as you well know. But it's meant to be a communication tool first, an adventure playground perhaps second. You can't invent words unless your books sell as many as Mrs Rowling, say (and she introduces new terms in a reader-friendly way). ELU looks at standard usages. There are other sites for experimental cryptography.

Comment: @Lawrence An acronym being in use already, isn't sufficient argument not to adhere a new usage, in my opinion. We need to consider how vastly spread the original meaning is, the likelihood of confusion in practical usage, availability of equivalently adequate alternatives etc. There's a disambiguation page in every dictionary for a reason.   :)

Comment: I really liked *RIN*. Thinking about introducing it. Funny, though - the Swedish version would be *Svara Om Behövligt*, which opens for a confusion of a less polite kind.